# -d : not matching my folder

Tags: perl, directory, exists

I have a problem with this code. It matches the directories `.` and `..` but not the others. Can you explain me why?

```
my $Checked_directory = $Tested_directory . '\Sources';

opendir(Checked_directory, $Checked_directory)
    or print STDOUT "\n 101 - Cant open $Checked_directory: $!\n";

@files = readdir(Checked_directory);    #etablished the list of file in the checked folder

foreach my $fileToTest (@files) {

  print $fileToTest . "\n";    #debug

  if ($fileToTest =~ m/.jpg$/) {
    print 'file...  ' . $fileToTest . "\n";
    $Localisation_file = $Tested_directory . '\Sources\\' . $fileToTest;    #file to test
  }
  elsif (-d $fileToTest) {
    print ">>>>" . $fileToTest . "\n";
  }
}

closedir(Checked_directory);
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Have you tried doing `print  $fileToTest` to see what it is you're trying to read?

Comment: I try to print it and my folders are actually in @files

Comment: What do you mean by "It matches the directories . and .. but not the others". Are you saying the loop through @files only ever sees . and .. or something else? BTW, if you are looking for files with jpeg extensions then m/.jpg$/ should be m/\.jpg$/.

Comment: Actually, rereading your subject says -d not matching folder. If your directories all end in some character + 'jpg' the first if test will be true and the -d will never be tested. Perhaps give us an example of what files and directories you have.

Comment: The directory were in the list but nothing happend with the fonction -d. The suggestion of Borodin works pretty well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names in `@files`, as you seem to be aware, don't have any path information, which means the `-d` looks for them in the current working directory, fails to find them, and reports false. The same would happen with an `-e` (exists) test.

You should alter your code like this. Note that identifiers that start with capital letters are reserved for global identifiers. It is also a bad idea to use bareword file and directory handles -- lexical handles are current best practice.

```
my $checked_directory = "$tested_directory\\Sources";

opendir $checked_dh, $checked_directory
    or print STDOUT "\n 101 - Cant open $checked_directory: $!\n";

while (my $file_to_test = readdir $checked_dh) {

  print "$file_to_test\n";

  my $localisation_file = "$tested_directory\\Sources\\$file_to_test";

  if (-d $localisation_file) {
    print ">>>> $file_to_test\n";
  }
  elsif ($file_to_test =~ /\.jpg$/) {
    print "file... $file_to_test\n";
  }
}

closedir $checked_dh;
```

Comment: You are right. I need a complete path to use this fonction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so a quick test on your code - I've mocked up a directory structure. Looks like you're 'doing it windows style?'

I'm using this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Tested_directory = 'C:\\temp';

my $Checked_directory = $Tested_directory . '\Sources';
opendir( Checked_directory, $Checked_directory )
    or print STDOUT "\n 101 - Cant open $Checked_directory: $!\n";
my @files = readdir(Checked_directory)
    ;    #etablished the list of file in the checked folder
foreach my $fileToTest (@files) {
    print "File: $fileToTest \n";    #debug
    if ( $fileToTest =~ m/.jpg$/ ) {
        print 'file...  ' . $fileToTest . "\n";
        my $Localisation_file =
            $Tested_directory . '\Sources\\' . $fileToTest;  #file to test
    }
    else {
        print "\n$fileToTest is not a jpg\n";
    }

    if ( -d $fileToTest ) {
        print ">>>>" . $fileToTest . "\n";
    }
}
closedir(Checked_directory);
```

And I've created a directory structure looking like this:

```
 Directory of C:\temp\Sources

22/01/2015  13:07    <DIR>          .
22/01/2015  13:07    <DIR>          ..
22/01/2015  13:07                 0 notajpg.jpg
22/01/2015  13:04    <DIR>          SubDir
22/01/2015  13:07                 6 wibble.txt
               2 File(s)              6 bytes
```

And indeed - my 'SubDir' doesn't get `>>>>` prefixed in the output.

```
File: . 
>>>>.
File: .. 
>>>>..
File: notajpg.jpg 
file...  notajpg.jpg
File: SubDir 
File: wibble.txt
```

So your `.jpg` bit is working fine. But where '.' and '..' pick up as dirs, 'SubDir' does not.

The reason seems to be related to path. `.` and `..` exist in every directory, so that test will work regardless of script path.

You need to test against `( -d "$Checked_directory\\$fileToTest" )`

Giving:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Tested_directory = 'C:\\temp';

my $Checked_directory = $Tested_directory . '\Sources';
opendir( Checked_directory, $Checked_directory )
    or print STDOUT "\n 101 - Cant open $Checked_directory: $!\n";
my @files = readdir(Checked_directory)
    ;    #etablished the list of file in the checked folder
foreach my $fileToTest (@files) {
    print "File: $fileToTest \n";    #debug
    if ( $fileToTest =~ m/.jpg$/ ) {
        print 'file...  ' . $fileToTest . "\n";
        my $Localisation_file =
            $Tested_directory . '\Sources\\' . $fileToTest;  #file to test
    }
    elsif ( -d "$Checked_directory\\$fileToTest" ) {
        print ">>>>" . $fileToTest . "\n";
    }
}
closedir(Checked_directory);
```

Comment: Works with my rather simplistic test case.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't spot that you were using `$Checked_directory` instead of the OP's `$Tested_directory`. (Don't those two mean the same thing?!)